# What type of underlayment is appropriate for metal roofing?

Tags: underlayment, metal-roof

I'm building a shed with a metal roof. What underlayment material should go between my OSB roof deck and the steel panels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to always follow the metal roofing manufacturer’s recommendations for installation, but generally you can use 1-layer of 15# building paper if the slope is 4:12 or greater and it’s standing seam metal roof with concealed fasteners.

You need a minimum of 2-layers 15# building paper if it’s a slope between 2:12 and 4:12.

Below 2:12 slope you need to follow the manufacturer’s recommendation for installation. (They’ll probably recommend a peel-and-stick underlayment.)

Answer (score 0):

My roofers used Feltbuster under my standing seam metal roof about 7 yrs ago. I've had no issues. Although I think this stuff is fairly expensive. Not sure I'd spend that for a tool or mower shed--but if your shed will house more delicate/valuable items, I'd use it.